# Windows server 2003 find user's computer

Tags: windows-server-2003, users, session

I would like to see which computer is used by a user (where he's working on), is it possibile to check user session in domain's computers?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see this if you search/look in your security event logs on your server. If you search for the login name you should see when and on which computer (name and ip) that your user logged in to.

Comment: Only if that server happens to be a domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility by the name of "loggedon2" which works on Server 2003 (I'm not sure if it works on newer versions) that will allow you to see who is logged onto which machine(s). You can either scan one machine or the entire network.

Comment: Nothing inside WS2003?

Comment: @Tobia, only in the logs, if you have appropriate logging enabled and it's a domain controller, but good luck finding what you need in that lot. If you have multiple domain controllers you need to check the logs on each one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Sure. Open task manager. Click on users. Then right click on the user you want to connect and then select connect option and you are done. 
Even you can disconnect the users who are logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question.